# What is the best way to add data on a daily basis to a tableview in my published iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, database

I have a tableview in an app which is holding much more data in an array than it should be.
I would like to publish the app with the current data and continue to upload data into that tableview daily in the near future.

Is it possible to have the data added to the tableview daily in the same way that I've been adding it into the viewController through a swift file before it was published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the firebase database to store data and show them on daily basis to a `tableview`. Whenever firebase database will be updated, iOS application will get database change notification. You can update your `tableview` based on this notification with the new data. Firebase even has offline capabilities which means it can persist data locally so that data can be accessed when there is no internet connection.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities

Comment: I have added a comment there, please check whether that helps. :)